# Opening Word from Python, unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-word

I'm writing a script to parse word document and get certain outputs. I use the following commands for reading the desired document.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import Tkinter,tkFileDialog

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename() # getting filename through windows explorer

word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
#word.Documents.Open(filename)
```

The last line which is commented is how I was planning to implement this. But whenever I try to open a file which has a space in it's filename, this fails. In fact I found that if I give `word.Documents.Open("C:/Python27/word sample.docm")`
This will also fail, but if I use backslash after `C:` it'll work perfectly.

In short the below commands for opening document will work:

```
word.Documents.Open("C:\Python27/word sample.docm")
word.Documents.Open(filename) #if filename don't have a space
```

And the below ones will not work:

```
word.Documents.Open("C:/Python27/word sample.docm")
word.Documents.Open(filename) #filename have a space in it
```

Could someone explain what is going wrong here?

This is the error that I'm receiving:

```
C:\Users\xxx>C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    word.Documents.Open("C:/Python27/word sample.docm")
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 8, in Open
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Word'
, u'This file could not be found.\r (C:\\//Python27/word%20sample.docm)', u'
wdmain11.chm', 24654, -2146823114), None)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `os.path.normpath(...)` on your filename before passing it to windows?

Comment: Thanks!! I think it's working. Could you just briefly mention what was I doing wrong.